# How to approximate higher-degree multivariate polynomial in space of lower-degree multivariate polynomials with some constraints?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, optimization

For a polynomial $P_{1}(x)$, $x\in {\mathbb R}^n$ with a higher-degree, how to find a lower-degree polynomial $P_{2}(x)$ with determined structure or bounded degree  to approximate it with the constraint:
$$\{x|P_{2}(x) \le 0\} \subseteq \{x|P_{1}(x) \le 0\}$$
I hope the algorithm can manipulate coefficients directly and be free from computing the value of $P_{i}(x)$. However, a high efficient algorithm which needs to compute $P_{i}(x)$ is acceptable as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution, but too long for a comment, and might be useful.

Let's deal with the univariate case first, and let's suppose we are working on the interval $[-1,1]$. It's fairly clear how to approximate a polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ by another one $g$ of degree $n-1$. If the coefficient of $x^n$ in $f$ is $a$, you set $g = f-ah$, where $h$ is the monic Chebyshev polynomial of degree $n$. With this construction, $g$ is the best possible approximation of $f$ (in the uniform norm) by a polynomial of degree $n-1$.

The approximation error $e$ is known -- it's the norm of $h$, which is $1/2^n$, I think. Then $k = g+e$ is also a very good approximation of $f$, and $k \ge f$, so
$\{x \in \mathbb{R} : k(x) \le 0\} \subseteq \{x \in \mathbb{R} : f(x) \le 0\}$.

Possibly all of this extends to the multivariate case somehow.